# use custom class in laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using following library for credit card payment:

https://github.com/CKOTech/checkout-php-library

i have added code of above library in app\Libraries folder, following is the file i want to include now:
[image]

I added following code in my Controller where i want to use this library:

```
use com\checkout\ApiClient;
$apiClient = new ApiClient('sk_CC937715-4F68-4306-BCBE-640B249A4D50');
```

But i am getting following error: Please guide.

FatalErrorException in WelcomeController.php line 23:
Class 'com\checkout\ApiClient' not found

Comment: If you have not installed it through composer, did you add the file or path to your autoloader? If so, `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: That library is a `composer` project. Don't add it manually, simply go to Laravel installation directory and run `composer require checkout/checkout-php-api`. Composer does the rest. Whenever possible, you want to avoid doing stuff manually, like downloading and adding libraries.

Comment: i didn't add library from composer, just downloaded it from github

Comment: Then you have to include it, if didn't use composer.
include 'folder_of_lib/class_of_api.php';